# Montar consulta Mysql no Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Senhores, tenho a seguinte consulta no mysql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') as 'year', DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') as 'month', COUNT(id) as 'total' FROM emprestimos GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%m')
```

Porem estou apanhando para montar ela no Laravel, alguma dica em como ela ficaria?

Estou tentando como

```
DB::table('emprestimos')->select('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y as year)')->select('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %m as month')->count('id as total')->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, %Y%m');
```

mas sem sucesso!

Obrigado

Comment: Tente usar DB:raw($sqlQuery), aqui eu uso colchetes para para select as ex: ->select(['id as total']) e se passo parâmetro no select como você, geralmente vai em Raw também ->select([DB:raw('DATE_FORMAT(xyz) as abc')])

Comment: tentei assim Emprestimos::select(DB::raw(["DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') year"]), DB::raw(["DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') month"]))
            ->count('id')
            ->groupBy([DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at) `%Y%m`')]); e não rolou @LeonardoGetulio

Comment: Mano, os colchetes estão no lugar errado. Também você poderia montar o select 1 parte por vez, ai você vai vendo onde está a falha. Leia também a documentação do laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Valew @LeonardoGetulio

Comment: Cristiano, se resolveu poste como resposta, não direto na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução foi

```
$valores = Emprestimos::select([
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') as year"),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') as month"),
    DB::raw("count(id) as total")
])
->groupBy('year')
->groupBy('month')
->get();
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Show, vou adicionar!

Comment: Na verdade basta fazer `YEAR(created_at)` e `MONTH(created_at)`...